# How to consume Request Body (JSON) along with multiple files (multipart/form-data) via REST API in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflux

I want to consume both JSON & files in an API for my spring boot application (using Spring WebFlux). I tried multiple ways as was recommended over the internet ([Article1](https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/07/27/requestbody-and-multipart-on-spring-boot/), [Article2](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/01/problem-with-modelattribute-while.html?m=1), [Article3](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests)), but it's not working for me. The API is not being hit and getting status 415 (Unsupported Media Type) from [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYWuw.png).

**Spring-Boot version :** 2.5.3

**Spring-Web/Webflux version :** 5.3.9

**Employee :**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int mobileNo;
    private List<MultipartFile> files;

}
```

**Controller :**

```
@PostMapping(path = "employee", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public Mono<Response> processEmployeeDocs(@RequestPart Employee request, @RequestPart List<MultipartFile> files) {
    Employee employee = new Employee(request.getName(), request.getAge(), request.getMobileNo(), files);
    return employeeService.processDocs(employee);
}
```

Comment: Please share implementation of `employeeService.processDocs`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using MultipartFile use FilePart to consume multipart content as per the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart-forms)

Below is the working code snippet

```
@PostMapping(path = "employees", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> processEmployeeDocs(@RequestPart Employee request, @RequestPart Flux<FilePart> files) {
    log.info("processing request {}", request);
    return files.flatMap(part -> part.transferTo(Paths.get("temp", File.separator, part.filename())))
            .then(employeeService.processDocs(request))
            .then(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().build()));
}
```

The above code will save the files in "temp" directory. You can use those files for processing your logic.

Postman Request
[image]